# Interact function won't run more than once in my notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am working through a Udemy course for python and currently on a section for GUI's and working with the interact module.  When I first start the notebook and run the code below the output is as expected.

```python
from ipywidgets import interact,interactive,fixed
import ipywidgets as widgets

def func(x):
    return x

interact(func,x=10)
```

The output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiTVT.png).  However, when I try to modify the return statement and rerun the function, I get [the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE4Zs.png).

If I select Kernel -> Restart & Run All, the output will display again.

I am running python 3.8.10 in Jupyter Notebook with server 6.5.4 on an Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS container with Coder version 1.42.0.

I am not getting any errors at least on the notebook itself.  I think it's a notebook problem but don't know where the logs are to see if there are any errors.

Comment: That may only be reproducible on your system or environment. Or you somehow broke the function `func` in an earlier intermediate you aren't showing. Did you restart the kernel? You can go [here](https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila) and choose to use the launch badge under 'Direct links to start out in notebook mode in JupyterLab full-featured mode:' You'll see there the code works as expected. Or to use JupyterLite go to [here](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and choose the orange JupyterLab badge in the upper left. When that comes up, open a new notebook and run...

Comment: <continued> in a new cell `%pip install -q ipywidgets`. Then try your code and it should work as you expect there, too. If you are using Anaconda in your container, you should be able to sort out if it is reproducible in the environment or not. Or if Anaconda/conda isn't involved, maybe you need to adjust the versions in the container to see what is causing it, **if it isn't just caused by a hidden state issue with something you aren't showing**?

Comment: Thanks @Wayne.  Hopefully I'll get a chance to take a look into it next week.